# SQL query to get first and last of a sequence

Tags: sql, ms-access

With the following query ...

```
select aa.trip_id, aa.arrival_time, aa.departure_time, aa.stop_sequence, aa.stop_id, bb.stop_name
from  OeBB_Stop_Times aa
left join OeBB_Stops bb on aa.stop_id = bb.stop_id
```

I get the following table:

[image: img1]

Now I want the first and last line/value from the column stop_sequence referring to column `trip_id`, so the result should be:

[image: img2]

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: SQL is just a language used by multiple dbms.  What's your platform???

Comment: I'm using Windows 10, MS Access as database and Visual Studio 2015 (VB.net) as programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a sub-query to get the min and max and join against that data.
Like this:

```
select aa.trip_id, aa.arrival_time, aa.departure_time, aa.stop_sequence, aa.stop_id, bb.stop_name
from  OeBB_Stop_Times aa
join (
   SELECT trip_id, max(stop_sequence) as max_stop, min(stop_sequence) as min_stop
   FROM OeBB_Stop_Times
   GROUP BY trip_di
) sub on aa.trip_id = sub.trip_id AND (aa.stop_sequence = sub.max_stop or aa.stop_sequence = sub.min_stop)
left join OeBB_Stops bb on aa.stop_id = bb.stop_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function twice to filter out rows, as in:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by trip_id order by arrival_time) as rn,
    row_number() over(partition by trip_id order by arrival_time desc) as rnr
  from OeBB_Stop_Times
) x
where rn = 1 or rnr = 1
order by trip_id, arrival_time
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select s.*
from (select st.trip_id, st.arrival_time, st.departure_time, 
             st.stop_sequence, st.stop_id, s.stop_name,
             row_number() over (partition by st.trip_id order by st.stop_sequence) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by st.trip_id order by st.stop_sequence desc) as seqnum_desc
      from OeBB_Stop_Times st left join
           OeBB_Stops s
           on st.stop_id = s.stop_id
     ) s
where 1 in (seqnum_asc, seqnum_desc);
```

Note that I fixed the table aliases so they are meaningful rather than arbitrary letters.

Actually, if the `stop_sequence` is guaranteed to start at 1, this is a bit simpler:

```
select s.*
from (select st.trip_id, st.arrival_time, st.departure_time, 
             st.stop_sequence, st.stop_id, s.stop_name,
             max(stop_sequence) over (partition by st.trip_id) as max_stop_sequence
      from OeBB_Stop_Times st left join
           OeBB_Stops s
           on st.stop_id = s.stop_id
     ) s
where stop_sequence in (1, max_stop_sequence);
```

Comment: @HeinKurz . . . Then use the first query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- for a MAX windowing function you need a range qualifier -- `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`

Comment: @Hogan . . . Not in most databases.